# Regex to replace a special character in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I have problem with a special character `§`. I want to replace multiple occurrences of `§` with single `§`. The following regex works fine on [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/).

```
$file_data = file_get_contents($file_name);
$file_data = preg_replace('/\§+/g', '§',$file_data);
```

It changed

> §§§§§§§§§This free 3D robot game could redefine how kids learn to codeDigital Trends
>   It’s hard to get kids to code. Up until very recently, it was largely ....

to

> §This free 3D robot game could redefine how kids learn to codeDigital Trends
>   It’s hard to get kids to code. Up until very recently, it was largely ....

However, it is not working on the server after I upload it. Here is the `var_dump($file_data)` by PHP

> Â§Â§Â§Â§Â§Â§Â§Â§
>   This free 3D robot game could redefine how kids learn to codeDigital Trends
>   It’s hard to get kids to code. Up until very recently, it was largely ....

So, there seems to be an additional character `Â` before every `§` in the `var_dump`. The extra character `Â` does not show up on webpage when echoed as HTML. It just shows up during plain PHP `var_dump`. How can I replace multiple occurrences of `§` using regex in PHP?

Comment: I would start by removing the `g` modifier since it doesn't exist in php regex. My first guess would be to try the `u` modifier: `/§+/u`. Have fun

Comment: Second guess: make sure to use utf-8 in your html document or send a header beforehand to define the type: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: @HamZa Thank you. It was working on regex101 so I thought it would work on server too. I would see if it solves the problem.

Comment: @HamZa The document is a `.dat` file with HTML content.

Comment: I would probably use `"§" . ltrim($file_data, "§")`

Comment: @HamZa It is working now. What you said about using `u` was correct. If you write it as an answer I will accept it. Otherwise, I will accept the other answer which does what your comment says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set the `u` (utf-8) modifier:

From perlre documentation:

> **/u** 
>   means to use Unicode rules when pattern matching. On ASCII platforms, this means that the code points between 128 and 255 take on their Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) meanings (which are the same as Unicode's)....

```
$output = preg_replace('/§+/u', '§', $input);
                         // ^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str="§§§§§§§§§This free 3D robot game could redefine how kids learn to codeDigital Trends It's hard to get kids to code. Up until very recently, it was largely ....";
$pttn='@\§{2,}@um';
echo preg_replace( $pttn,'§',$str );

/* will output */
/*
   §This free 3D robot game could redefine how kids learn to codeDigital Trends It's hard to get kids to code. Up until very recently, it was largely .... 
*/
```